# Usefulness of Lockfree programming on Userlevel Threads

Tags: multithreading, lock-free

AFAIK, as opposed to time-slice based scheduler preemption, pure User-level threads(ULTs) have the property of yielding the processor to the other threads. However, from my surfing on internet I see that we have several preemptive User Thread mechanisms now.

Keeping this in mind, wanted to start a discussion on benefits of Lock-free programming on User level threads. My understanding is that irrespective of presence of preemptive scheduler performance of Lock free programming should surpass that of mutex/semaphore based programs.

However, I am still confused; since acquire operation on mutex also takes fast-path in the absence of contention, performance gain need not be attractive enough to migrate to Lock-free approach.

In case of semaphores, there is a invocation to system call leading to context switch and hence lock-free approaches can be seen as much better option.

Please suggest for both the situations - ULT equipped with preemptive mechanism and the one without it.

Comment: Do you have an actual code or design problem that you wish to solve?

Comment: I am afraid. Actually NO. I am working for a company that uses User Level Threads and has preemptive library. There are several data-structures including some that allocate(use) memory from preallocated heap which is designed a Radix Tree. I am just cautious and curious whether to go for Lockfree approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock-free programming"? If you do IO then you will eventualy need locks, no matter what the architecture is.

Comment: @freakish - I am not sure I get you. By Lock-free I mean lock free approach to regular insert/delete/read operation on data-structures. Did you mean that we need to protect a descriptor by synchronization mechanisms and that is why we need locks while I/O?

Comment: Lets say that you have a web application and you have an in-memory cache. This cache is supposed to be invalidated every 5mins and invalidation happens on a web request. If two web requests invalidate at the same time then you may (or may not, it depends) need a lock to ensure that the cache is consistent. For example if you need two requests to DB in order to fill the cache, then two web requests do 4 db requests in total. This may lead to inconsistency. Unless you block entire app for the duration of a request. But I assume that you would switch context on IO.

Comment: You cannot have one without the other.  Whatever "lock-free" low-level primitive you use is never going to cause the operating system's thread scheduler to cause a context switch.  You really *do* need a semaphore or mutex when blocking is required and/or good concurrency is desired.  Once you start bolting a yield on top of a failed CAS then you are no longer ahead.

Comment: 'Lock-free' just sounds good.  Clueless devs. think 'lock-free' means 'deadlock-free', which is sorta correct except that livelock is hugely worse than deadlock. Also, 'lock-free' almost guarantees high-purrrformance, (not).

Comment: @Hans - +1. I understand the significance of minimal blocking which is available with lock-based mechanisms. However, that problem stays alike for both user level or hybrid (e.g. POSIX) threads. One can always come with a better yield() policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy question to answer, as it is very general, it will boil down to what your requirements are.

I have recently been working with systems where the use of lock free structures was considered, but when we sat down and wrote out our requirements, we realized that they are in fact not what we want. Our system didn't really require them, and in fact locking helps us because we typically have a producer/consumer architecture where if there is nothing being produced (i.e. nothing being added to a queue) then the consumer should be idle (i.e. blocked).

I recently wrote about this in more detail:
http://blog.chrisd.info/a-simple-thread-safe-queue-for-use-in-multi-threaded-c-applications/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the concern. I presumed that for high contention cases which can be adjusted to fit to have atomic manipulation operations, are potential candidates of lock-free programming. For Example, if multiple threads are using a Radix Tree quite often we may try to use a lock free Radix Tree.

Comment: Well, consider the fact that a lock free radix tree is non-trivial, and not commonly available in libraries that I know of.